# iOS: Get Redirect URL (specifically from Venmo)

Tags: objective-c, oauth, venmo

I am using the Venmo iOS SDK, which uses OAuth. I am able to send the user to Venmo to request permissions, then it returns to my app using a redirect URL on my web server. The redirect sends the user to my app in this form: `http://www.mygreatapp.com/venmo_oauth?access_token=4e4sw1111111111t8an8dektggtcbb45` . I need to be able to get this exact URL so I can parse the access_token to get the JSON data. How do I get this URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
if ([[Venmo sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"return URL %@", url);
    return YES;
}
// You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
return NO;
}
```